# Limit Access to Website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows-authentication

I am very new to setting up security on a website.  I am using Windows Authentication and would like to limit access to my website so that only users in a Windows Security Group can open the website, and everyone else would get an Access is denied error.  In my AD, I belong to the security group MIS\ICT_Dept, where MIS is the organizational unit, and the security group name is ICT_Dept.

If I allow the MIS\ICT_Dept only, anyone can get in.  If I allow the MIS\ICT_Dept and deny all users, I can't get in even though I am a member of MIS\ICT_Dept.  Here is my web.config with the deny users (I started setting it up with ASP security, and then switched to Windows - if you see code that is no longer needed, please let me know):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=WillSQL\ict2;Initial Catalog=timesql_testing;Integrated Security=SSPI"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TimeSQLConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=WillSQL\ict2;Initial Catalog=TimeSQL_testing;Integrated Security=SSPI"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TimeSQLConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=WILLSQL\ict2;Initial Catalog=TimeSQL_testing;Integrated Security=SSPI"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <globalization culture="en-us" />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="mis\ICT_Dept" />
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.4" newVersion="2.1.0.4" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Thanks!  Here's the modified code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=WillSQL\ict2;Initial Catalog=timesql_testing;Integrated Security=SSPI"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TimeSQLConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=WillSQL\ict2;Initial Catalog=TimeSQL_testing;Integrated Security=SSPI"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TimeSQLConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=WillSQL\ict2;Initial Catalog=TimeSQL_testing;Integrated Security=SSPI"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>

    <globalization culture="en-us" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="ICT_Dept"/>
      <deny users ="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` element.  Also, make sure you have Windows Authentication enabled in IIS.

Comment: In IIS, Windows Authentication is the only one Enabled.  I added that code and I'm still getting an error - 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
I did try to change it to allow users="mislan\janet", and I'm getting the same error.  One thing - when I go to import it into IIS, I'm getting an error on CREATE USER [spacheco] for LOGIN[MISLAN\spacheco].  User ... already exists in the current database.  I can't even find the code where it would try to create this user...   Not sure if this has something to do with it???

Comment: The error you get must come from the profile provider or there is some custom code doing so. Try turn off the profile provider to see if you get rid of the error, else run in debug if you run locally.

Comment: About the authentication issue, you should try to use ? instead of * to prevent unauthenticated users not all users.

Comment: @user3033348, any luck?

Comment: Julien - I've been away from my desk the last couple of days, but I will try it today.  I'll let you know.  Thanks for asking!

Comment: Got it to work.  Even though, I have allow roles="ICT_Dept" and denyusers ="?" in my web.config, when I import it into IIS, All Users is inherited under Authorization Rules and "ICT_Dept" doesn't even show.  If I look under .NET Authorization Rules, it shows ICT_Dept Allow, Anonymous Users Deny, and All Users Inherited Allow.  If I don't mess w/ .NET Authorization Rules, but modify Authorization Rules to allow ICT_Dept and nothing else, it works.  How can I get this to come from my web.config.  What I am not coding correctly?  I'll modify my question to include the modified code at the end.